# Extract data from Sheet1 into Sheet2 from a list of data

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to scripting and I find myself stuck on what I feel like is an easy solution. In summary, in excel, I have all my data on Sheet1(import) and I want to pull data from that list into my Sheet2(export) using Column A (on my Sheet2) as my list of data to pull.

I have managed to get the data to pull however, I am not able to get it to pull multiples. Example, I have ABC in my Column A (Sheet2), I click my button to pull data, it pulls the first ABC on Sheet1 that it finds then stops. I need it to pull all the ABC's off sheet1 before moving onto the next cell to search.

This is my first post so I apologize if this is a rough read or I should have added more content.

---------------Code----------------

```
Private Sub DataImport_Click()

Dim I, Total, fRow As Integer
Dim Found As Range

'Listed Data to locate
Total = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Where to locate data to export
For I = 2 To Total
    answer1 = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & I).Value
    Set Found = Sheets(1).Columns("F").Find(What:=answer1, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=x1Next)

'To Do when there is no data
If Found Is Nothing Then
'Leave the cell blank

'To Do when there is data & where/what data to pull
Else
    fRow = Sheets(1).Columns("F").Find(What:=answer1, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=x1Next).Row
    Worksheets(2).Range("C" & I).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("F" & fRow).Value
    Worksheets(2).Range("D" & I).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("G" & fRow).Value
    Worksheets(2).Range("E" & I).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("H" & fRow).Value
    Worksheets(2).Range("F" & I).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("C" & fRow).Value
    Worksheets(2).Range("G" & I).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("E" & fRow).Value


End If
Next I


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only processing the first found item. You can use a `Do` loop to process all of them as below.

```
Set Found = Sheets(1).Columns("F").Find(What:=answer1, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=x1Next)
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
   Do Until Found Is Nothing
      'your logic for each found item
       Set Found = Sheets(1).Columns("F").FindNext(Found)
   Loop
End If
```

Comment: Kevin,

I have added the Do loop, but the code is giving me "invalid or unqualified reference" when I attempt to run. Debug highlights the .FindNext.

I will continue to research what I am missing; if I locate an answer prior to a reply I'll let you know what I came up with.

Thank you for your response, glad I am at least on the correct path.

Comment: Sorry I had my test code wrapped in at With block. Please change to:  `Sheets(1).Columns("F").FindNext(Found)`

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help and after getting many possible solutions to the issue we ended up using this code found below. Thank you again to all the help!

```
Private Sub ExtractData_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim intSourceRowCt As Integer
    Dim intSearchRowCt As Integer
    Dim intCopyToRow As Integer
    'Set row to Start Copying to
    intCopyToRow = 2
    'Listed Data to locate
    intSourceRowCt = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    intSearchRowCt = Sheets(1).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Loop through Source
    For i = 2 To intSourceRowCt
        'Loop through Search
        For j = 2 To intSearchRowCt
            'Copy Row if Matches
            If (Worksheets(1).Range("F" & j).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & i).Value) Then
                Worksheets(2).Range("C" & intCopyToRow).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("F" & j).Value
                Worksheets(2).Range("D" & intCopyToRow).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("G" & j).Value
                Worksheets(2).Range("E" & intCopyToRow).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("H" & j).Value
                Worksheets(2).Range("F" & intCopyToRow).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("C" & j).Value
                Worksheets(2).Range("G" & intCopyToRow).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("E" & j).Value
                'Increment Insert Row
               intCopyToRow = intCopyToRow + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```